# Создание константной строки по условию

Tags: c++, строки, инициализация, const

Есть код следующего вида:

```
std::string str;
if (x > 0) str = "positive";
else if (x < 0) str = "negative";
else str = "zero";
```

Хочется переписать код так, чтобы `str` было бы константой.
Как это сделать "красиво"? Некрасиво - создать функцию, "вычисляющую" эту строку, и вернуть её:

```
const std::string str = Foo ();
```

Или вообще создать прямо тут на месте лямбду... Но так не хочется :) .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
const std::string str = x > 0 ? "positive" : x < 0 ? "negative" : "zero";
```

Так годится?

Comment: О, минусатор на охоте - второй минус за сегодня. Анонимно и без пояснений, почему.

Comment: Хороший вариант, спасибо. Правда в моём коде там не 3 пути ветвления, а 10+ (под свичом), но на тот вопрос, что я написал, это действительно ответ. Если это раскрывать на большее количество путей ветвления, код станет страшным...

Answer (score 0):

Ну если без функции, то можно на месте сначала задать аргументы конструктора, а затем только создавать строку с `const` квалификатором.

```
char const * psz_value{};
::std::size_t value_length{}
if (x < 0)
{
    constexpr auto const & sz_value{"negative"}
    psz_value = sz_value;
    value_length = ::std::size(sz_value) - 1;
}
else if (0 == x)
{
    constexpr auto const & sz_value{"zero"}
    psz_value = sz_value;
    value_length = ::std::size(sz_value) - 1;
}
else
{
    constexpr auto const & sz_value{"positive"}
    psz_value = sz_value;
    value_length = ::std::size(sz_value) - 1;
}
::std::string const str{psz_value, value_length};
```

Но я бы вообще засунул эти строки в таблицу вместо пересоздания каждый раз.

Comment: Вы как-то умудрились собрать в код-стайле все маргинальные веяния. :Р East const, `::`, венгерская нотация, uniform инициалицация...

Answer (score 0):

Если это локальная переменная, то можно объявить дополнительную константную ссылку :

```
std::string str_pri;
std::string const & str = str_pri ;
if (x > 0) str_pri = "positive";
else if (x < 0) str_pri = "negative";
else str_pri = "zero";
```

А если глобальная переменная, то можно рабочую спрятанную переменную хранить в отдельном исходнике, а в открытый доступ передавать только константную ссылку.

public.hpp :

```
extern std::string const & str_pub ;
```

private.cpp :

```
static std::string str_pri;
std::string const & str_pub = str_pri ;

if (x > 0) str_pri = "positive";
else if (x < 0) str_pri = "negative";
else str_pri = "zero";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 const int i = x < 0 ? -1 : x == 0 ? x : 1;
 const string p[3] = { "negative", "zero", "positive" };
 const string str = p[i + 1];
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Уж тогда бы `const char **`, чтобы не мусорить.

Comment: @aleksandr barakin, постарайтесь оставлять более уместные комментарии...

Answer (score 0):

В общем случае это решается лямбдой:

```
const std::string str = [&]{
    std::string str;
    // str = ...
    return str;
}();
```

Но для такого простого случая я бы взял предложенный Harry `? :`.

Comment: Только сейчас увидел, что про лямбду вы уже подумали. Но, имхо, лучше ничего нет.

Comment: Спасибо, ответ хороший, хотя я и просил без лямбды ) Поставил вам плюс, за что минусуют - непонятно...